# Regular expression to match line containing some strings and not others

Tags: regex

I have lines like this:

```
example.com/p/stuff/...
example.com/page/thing/...
example.com/page/stuff/...
example.com/page/other-stuff/...
etc
```

where the dots represent continuing URL paths. I want to select URLs that contain `/page/` and are NOT followed by `thing/`. So from the above list we would select:

```
example.com/page/stuff/...
example.com/page/other-stuff/...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*?\/page\/[^(thing)].*`

this is the regex for matching a string which has `/page/` not followed by `thing`

adding the lazy evalation is suggested because you advance a char at the time, better performance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use negative lookahead:

```
example\.com\/page\/(?!thing\/).*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Mtvv4/2)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex pattern:

`.*?\/page\/(?!thing\/).*`

https://regex101.com/r/19wh1w/2

---

`(?!thing\/)` - negative lookahead assertion ensures that `page/` section is not followed by `thing/`